# awk print if capture group is a number greater/less than N

Tags: awk

I have log lines something like

```
10:00 3 foo
10:02 2 bar
10:05 7 baz
```

If I match this against the regex

```
^(\d\d:\d\d) (\d) (.*)$
```

then I want to print the whole line if and only if the second capture group is less than or equal to N.

e.g. if the condition was "capture group 2 is greater than 2" then the output would be

```
10:00 3 foo
10:05 7 baz
```

How can I do this in awk, or similar unix tool?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '$2>2' file
10:00 3 foo
10:05 7 baz
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output and a better explanation of your requirements.

If you really wanted to just learn how to use capture groups in awk, here's one way using the regexp from your question (but modified to use `[0-9]` instead of the non-POSIX `\d`) and GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]) ([0-9]) (.*)$/,a) && (a[2]>2)' file
10:00 3 foo
10:05 7 baz
```

Comment: Little bit more explicit version of @Ed Morton's solution if it helps to understand: awk '{if ($2>2) print $0}' Explanation: if field 2 is larger than 2, print entire row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sh
threshold=2
awk -v n=$threshold '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]$/ && $2 > n' file
```

Details:

- `-v n=$threshold` - passing the `threshold` variable to `awk` script as `n` variable
- `$1 ~ /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/` - the first field value must match the "two digits, `:`, two digits" pattern
- `&& $2 ~ /^[0-9]$/` - and the second field must only consist of a single digit
- `&& $2 > n` - and Field 2 value must be greater than `n`.

Note that `\d` is not supported by POSIX regex flavor used in `awk`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/iKOw6q):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='10:00 3 foo
10:02 2 bar
10:05 7 baz'

threshold=2

awk -v n=$threshold '$1 ~ /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]$/ && $2 > n' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
10:00 3 foo
10:05 7 baz
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
awk '/^[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2} [[:digit:]] / && $2>2' log.file
```

If it matches your desired pattern and the second field is larger than `2`, output the whole line.

A bit wordier, but as an alternative you can use pure bash, making use of capture groups:

```sh
while read -r; do
  [[ $REPLY =~ ^[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}[[:space:]]([[:digit:]])[[:space:]] ]] \
    && (( ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} > 2 )) \
    && echo "$REPLY"
done <<<"$content"
```

Comment: Regarding the bash solution, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)